# How to Store Image in SQLite Database in React Native

Tags: javascript, react-native, image, sqlite, imagepicker

I have taken an image with Image Picker and want to store it in sqlite database and retrive it. Should I store **uri** which I got in reponse from Image Picker or what should I do,

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My honest opinion is to use a dedicated storage space for your images, and store the url and the image meta data in your database.

You can store your image as a base64, however this will take up a lot of space in your database, and the conversion to base64 and back to binary may even make the image size bigger.

Stick to a storage solution for your image (Both Google and AWS offers them), and save the url in your database.

Regards
Stephan Bakkelund Valois

Comment: I'm doing a demo project. In which , accepting the form data which includes an image. 
I thought it will be good to store images with all the data in local database.    
                                                                                                                                                    
As you said, it will be a good idea to use dedicated storage space and store the url in
Database.
Thanks for suggestion!

Regards
Sachin S

Comment: You welcome! Please accept this as the answer if it helped you :-)

Answer (score 1):

you have to save image in local storage and save `uri` of that in `SQLite`. that's way is the better performance .

Comment: Yes, this will be the better way to do it. Thanks for the suggestion!, Regards Sachin S

Comment: your welcome , if that's your answer, please select green mark for other users.

Comment: @MeisamSaba storing of uri in the sqlite database is ok, but how to retrieve and show that image on the screen. When i done that URI is getting stored but not shwoing image instead of that blank space is showing. Do you have any idea to show that image on the screen.